# C++ template function selection based on whether argument is value or reference

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I currently have something like:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value,void>::type
f( T const &t ) {
  // ...
}
```

that is, I don't want `f` to be considered if `T` is an pointer type.  This works fine as-is. However, now I want two different versions of `f` based on whether its argument is a value returned by value vs. returned by reference:

```
std::string const& ret_by_ref();
std::string ret_by_val();

f( ret_by_ref() ); // I want the existing function to be called here
f( ret_by_val() ); // I want a new template specialization of f() called here
```

How can I augment the existing declaration of `f` and create a new `f` such that they are called as shown above?

A pre-C++-11 answer appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to distinguish pass in by value or pass in by reference ? If you overload those function, seems they gonna be ambiguous.

Comment: Because for by-reference, I want to cache the result; for by-value, caching the result is pointless since the object is temporary. Can you answer the question or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done with rvalue references. Just add

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value,void>::type
f( T &&t ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Any advice on pre-11 implementations ? (not possible is certainly valid).

Comment: WhozCraig: I don't think it can be done in C++ 2003: if it had been possible we wouldn't have needed rvalue references.

Answer (score -1):

For pre-11 compiler, you can always refer to boost type traits lib.

boost::is_pointer

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pointer.html

I suggest you start reading [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/background.html) for some 'Background and Tutorial' of type traits.

Comment: I'm aware of type traits and how they work. Also, the question is NOT about is_pointer. I'm looking for how to use an existing is_xxx or write my own for testing whether an argument is a reference-to-temporary, neither of which your answer provided.